# Stuck at "Signing into Multiplayer Services" in Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

I downloaded *Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition* on Steam and wanted to play online with friends, but every time I click the Multiplayer button, *AoE II* says "Signing into Multiplayer Services", and nothing happens. How can I sign into these services or make the game work?

Answer (score 0):

AoE2 DE employs a battle server that relies on XBOX service meaning you need an [Outlook](https://hotmail.com/) account to join the multiplayer dedicated servers.

Additionally windows 10 is the minimum requirement system to run the game.

## Once signed up an outlook account..

Run AOE2 through steam and top right window press: **Xbox Live Sign In**

[image: sign in age of empires 2 definitive multiplayer]

Insert your outlook email and password Then hit **Let's Play!**

[image: join xbox multiplayer]

## Multiplayer & Benchmark

At this point you can press the multiplayer shield to your left and a benchmark test will begin (30 - 50 seconds). If you score at least 900 points you will be instantly sent to the multiplayer screen which looks like..

[image: aoe2 de multiplayer tabs]

(Lobby Browser tab is the unranked section where people play casually)